# PropertyConfigurator.configure doesn't work with spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, log4j

i tried to initialize log4j logger using spring IOC and use PropertyConfigurator.configure to configure logger but PropertyConfigurator.configure doesn't work.
 the loggers are created using default configurations, the logging files are't created.

my Question is how to pass the configurations (log4j.properties) to Logger class ?

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
          <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Confugration class

```
@Configuration 
public class CommonConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
}

@Bean(name = "debugLogger")
public Logger debugLogger() {
    return Logger.getLogger("regDebug");
}

@Bean(name = "infoLogger")
public Logger infoLogger() {
    return Logger.getLogger("regOperational");
}

@Bean(name = "errorLogger")
public Logger errorLogger() {
  ic Logger infoLogger() {
    return Logger.getLogger("regError");
}}
```

log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.regDebug=DEBUG , stdout, regDebug
log4j.logger.regOperational=INFO, stdout , regOperational
log4j.logger.regError=ERROR , stdout , regError
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, console, regDebug, regOperational, regErro
log4j.appender.fileAppener=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

# STDOUT appender
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#DEBUG LEVEL
log4j.appender.regDebug.Append=true
log4j.appender.regDebug=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.regDebug.Append=true
log4j.appender.regDebug.File=D:/Code/log/COMMON_DEBUG.log
log4j.appender.regDebug.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.regDebug.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.regDebug.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH'.log'
log4j.appender.regDebug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.regDebug.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} || %5p || %t || %C{1} || %M:%L || %m%n

#INFO LEVEL

log4j.appender.regOperational=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.regOperational.Append=true
log4j.appender.regOperational.File=D:/Code/log/COMMON_ERROR.log
log4j.appender.regOperational.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH'.log'
log4j.appender.regOperational.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.regOperational.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} || %5p || %t || %m%n

#ERROR LEVEL

log4j.appender.regError=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.regError.Append=true
log4j.appender.regError.File=D:/Code/log/COMMON_ERROR.log
log4j.appender.regError.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH'.log'
log4j.appender.regError.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.regError.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} || %5p || %t || %C{1} || %M:%L || %m%n
```

Comment: You can modify the `init` method as static,and see the result.

Comment: the same issue , no different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot provides integration with Log4J via `spring-boot-starter-log4j` dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But first you need to exclude the default Spring Boot's logging mechanism:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Also, make sure your `log4j.properties` is located under `src/main/resources`. In this case you don't need to specify the file's path explicitly to `PropertyConfigurator` and can safely remove `init()` method.

Please note that Log4J 1.2.17 is quite outdated - it [reached the end of life in 2015](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/). You might want to consider using Log4J2 instead or stay with [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) - the default logging mechanism used by Spring Boot.

Comment: Finally, I see pom.xml declares `spring-context` dependency, which might cause conflict between Spring versions. Spring Boot already depends on Spring Core and Spring Context, so there's no need to declare it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksei Budiak